# Regex grouping and context

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been messing around with something I saw on twitter which to me makes sense but doesn't work as expected.

Why doesn't the first example work? (My regex could be wrong I suppose but it looks ok)

I expected the context of my `toUpperCase` call to be the group and be a shorthand version of the second example.

```
var output = "james".replace(/(^.+?)/,"".toUpperCase.call("$1"));


var output2 = "james".replace(/(^.+?)/,function(a){

    return "".toUpperCase.call(a);

    });

console.log(output); // outputs james
console.log(output2); // outputs James
```

***Edit*** I fixed the regex from a M42 comment. Bad pasting on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@M42 is correct, in that there's no reason that your first regex would match "james". But fixing it won't work either:

```
var output = "james".replace(/(^.+?)/,"".toUpperCase.call("$1"));
console.log(output); // outputs james
```

That's because there are two options for the second argument to `replace()`: a string or a function. If it's a string, then "$1" will be replaced with the first match (and so on). If it's a function, then the first argument will be the first match (and so on).

In your second example, you're using the function parameter, and correctly getting the first match as an argument. But in your first example, you're passing in the *result* of the function call `"".toUpperCase.call("$1")` - which, when you run it, returns the string `"$1"`. So the first example is actually using the string argument `"$1"` for `.replace()`, which does nothing but replace the first match in the string with itself:

```
"james".replace(/(^.+?)/,"$1"); // "james"
```

That's why this won't work as a shorthand - you're not actually passing in a function.

Comment: Ah right.. I had it the wrong way round in my head. Tricky stuff sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

The first example doesn't work because there is no match (i.e. there're no parens around the name). And more the hanchor `^` must not be placed after some char.

your regex:

```
/    : delimiter
\(   : open parens
(    : begining of group 1
^    : start of string
.+?  : one or more char non greedy
)    : end of group 1
\)   : close parens
/    : delimiter
```

this doesn't match `james`, so there is no replace or upperCased

Comment: By that do you mean the regex is wrong? If so, could you expand on that?

Comment: Cheers.  I hadn't noticed I'd pasted the wrong value for the first regex. I meant them to be the same.